# automatic authentication in a selenium python script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

hi how can i use a telegram bot to automatically authenticate myself on my selenium python script

here is my program:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyperclip
from telegram_verification import get_telegram_verification_code

chromedriver_path = '/Users/ppnop/Desktop/BOT TELEGRAM/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(chromedriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

def copier_dans_clipboard(chaine):
    pyperclip.copy(chaine)

driver.get("https://web.telegram.org/k")
time.sleep(2)

phone_number = "********"
log_with_phone = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "c-ripple")
log_with_phone.click()
time.sleep(4)

phone_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="auth
pages"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]')
copier_dans_clipboard(phone_number)
phone_input.click()
phone_input.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, 'v')
phone_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Attendre que le code de vérification soit envoyé
time.sleep(100)

# Récupérer le code de vérification depuis Telegram
api_id = "YOUR_API_ID"
api_hash = "YOUR_API_HASH"
bot_token = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"
verification_code = get_telegram_verification_code(api_id, api_hash, bot_token)

# Remplir le champ de code de vérification
verification_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "phone_verification_code")
verification_input.send_keys(verification_code)

# Continuer avec le processus d'authentification
verification_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Mettre une pause pour vérifier le résultat
time.sleep(10)
```

i want to automatiquely connect my telegram acount in the web telegram version
thank you in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.